# Zero Knowledge Police Check

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I’m curious if there’s a zero-knowledge protocol for the following. Suppose a Passer-by is stopped by a Vigilante who has a list of wanted criminals. Can the Passer-by prove he has a valid ID and he’s not on the list without disclosing his identity?

Assume the ID is a bunch of data signed by an authority in some way, anticipating just such a situation (this authority values liberty very much). Vigilantes must do no better than chance to distinguish between non-wanted Passers-by after arbitrarily many rounds of the protocol.

It’s also interesting if this is possible without the Passer-by learning the contents of the list.

Comment: This question [Zero knowledge proof for identity](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/52189/zero-knowledge-proof-for-identity) might help, and a search for, [zero knowledge proof identity](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/search?q=zero+knowledge+proof+identity) in this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly construct this with zero-knowledge proofs of knowledge, some one-way function $OW$ (lets say bijective for simplicity), and a signature schemes $\Sigma$.

## A simple protocol

- Citizens choose a random preimage $x$ of the one-way function. Their secret key is $x$, their public key is $y = OW(x)$.
- Citizens also store a state-issued signature $\sigma$ on $y$.
- You can prove arbitrary NP statements in zero-knowledge, i.e. statements of the form "I know $a,b,c$ such that [poly-time checkable statement about $a,b,c$]". 
  So assume the citizen is approached with a list of $y_1,\dots,y_n$ of wanted criminals' public keys.
  Both parties can then set up a zero-knowledge proof in which **the citizen proves**

  > "I know $x,y,\sigma$ such that $y = OW(x)$, and $\sigma$ is a valid
  >   signature on $y$, and $y\notin \{y_1,\dots,y_n\}$".

Zero-knowledge guarantees that the vigilante does not learn the values of $x,y,\sigma$. The proof of knowledge property guarantees that the citizen can only make the vigilante accept if he actually *knows* $x,y,\sigma$ with these properties. This (kinda) prevents a person on the list from winning the proof - they need some honest/unlisted person's secret $x$ and their signature $\sigma$, which only the honest person knows.

### Drawbacks

In practice, this simple scheme has limited applicability because wanted persons only need to convince *any* unlisted person to give them a copy of their $x,\sigma$. If they have that, they can easily pass the police check.
The underlying problem is that while physical IDs are (ideally) hard to copy, a digital identity is just a bunch of bits that is easily duplicated and handed over to another person.
You can probably make all of this more elaborate and give each person a trusted device that stores $x,\sigma$ in an unclonable way. But as soon as you have that, the zero-knowledge protocol becomes somewhat overkill - the police could just ask the trusted device whether it sees its identity on the list.

## Hiding the list

In the scheme listed above, the list contains no identifying information about the listed people (just a random value). You can however recognize values you have already seen before (e.g., friends). You could hide the list, for example, as follows:

- Assume for concreteness that the one-way function maps an integer $x$ to $OW(x) = g^x$ for some fixed $g$ in some prime-order group $\mathbb{G}$ where decisional Diffie-Hellman is hard.
- The signature stuff stays the same and the list is comprised of the criminals' public keys $g^{x_1},\dots,g^{x_n}$.
- Before showing the list to the citizen, the vigilante now randomizes the list to look random:

  - The vigilante chooses a random $r\leftarrow\mathbb{Z}_p$.
  - He then hands $h = g^r$ and $h^{x_1},\dots,h^{x_n}$ to the citizen.
  - Under the decisional Diffie-Hellman assumption, the elements $h^{x_i}$ are indistinguishable from random group elements. [1]
  - The citizen can still prove in a zero-knowledge proof of knowledge that he knows $x,y,\sigma$ such that $y = g^x$, $\sigma$ is a signature on $y$, and $h^x \notin \{h^{x_1},\dots h^{x_n}\}$.

[1]: of course, this only holds if the secret key $x_i$ of the entry is unknown to the citizen. Necessarily, each citizen must be able to recognize himself on the list. It's just all other entries that now look random.